# How to test MassTransit saga state machine with certain state?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, masstransit

I have state machine build with `MassTransit`:

```cs
public class OrderStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<Order>
{
    public State Completed { get; init; }
    public State Rejected { get; init; }

    public OrderStateMachine()
    {
        Event(() => OrderCreated, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.OrderId));
        Event(() => OrderCompleted, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.OrderId));

        Request(() => ReserveStock, cfg => { cfg.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); });
        Request(() => Checkout, cfg => { cfg.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); });
        
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState, 
            ReserveStock.Pending,
            Checkout.Pending,
            Completed, 
            Rejected);
        
        Initially(
            When(OrderCreated)
                .Then(x =>
                {
                    x.Saga.UserId = x.Message.UserId;
                    x.Saga.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                })
                .Request(ReserveStock, x => new ReserveStock
                {
                    OrderId = x.Saga.CorrelationId,
                    UserId = x.Saga.UserId
                })
                .TransitionTo(ReserveStock.Pending));

        During(ReserveStock.Pending,
            When(ReserveStock.Completed)
                .Then(x => x.Saga.ProductId = x.Message.ProductId)
                .Request(Checkout, x => new Checkout
                {
                    OrderId = x.Saga.CorrelationId,
                    UserId = x.Saga.UserId
                })
                .TransitionTo(Checkout.Pending),
            When(ReserveStock.Faulted)
                .TransitionTo(Rejected),
            When(ReserveStock.TimeoutExpired)
                .TransitionTo(Rejected));
        
        
    }
    
    public Event<OrderCreated> OrderCreated { get; init; }
    public Event<OrderCompleted> OrderCompleted { get; init; }
    
    public Request<Order, ReserveStock, StockReserved> ReserveStock { get; init; }
    public Request<Order, Checkout, PaymentCompleted> Checkout { get; init; }
}
```

Can't figure out how to create unit test for that state machine with initial state `ReserveStock.Pending` to test only `ReserveStock.Completed` transition. I have tried method with dictionary from [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2199)

```cs
    [Fact]
    public async Task StockReserved_Cause_Transition_To_Checkout_Pending()
    {
        await using var provider = _testFixture.GetProvider();
        var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
        await harness.Start();

        var dictionary = provider.GetRequiredService<IndexedSagaDictionary<Order>>();
        dictionary.Add(new SagaInstance<Order>(new Order 
        { 
            CorrelationId = _orderId,
            CurrentState = 3
        }));        

        var sendEndpoint = await harness.Bus.GetPublishSendEndpoint<StockReserved>();
        await sendEndpoint.Send(new StockReserved
        {
            OrderId = _orderId,
            UserId = _userId,
            ProductId = _productId,
        });

        var sagaHarness = harness.GetSagaStateMachineHarness<OrderStateMachine, Order>();
        await sagaHarness.Sagas.Any();
    }
```

but it does nothing

[image]

or i missed something

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I wrote for our test framework to achieve this, let me know if it works for you.

`AnswerSetCreated` is the message type that initializes a state machine instance.

```
protected override async Task<AnswerSetState> CreateInstanceInState(State state, Guid? answerSetId = null, Guid? formPackageInstanceId = null)
{
    answerSetId = Guid.NewGuid();
    formPackageInstanceId = Guid.NewGuid();

    await TestHarness.Bus.Publish(new AnswerSetCreated
    {
        AnswerSetId = answerSetId.Value,
        FormPackageInstanceId = formPackageInstanceId,
    });
    await SagaHarness.Consumed.Any<AnswerSetCreated>(x => x.Context.Message.AnswerSetId == answerSetId.Value);

    var dictionary = Provider.GetRequiredService<IndexedSagaDictionary<AnswerSetState>>();
    var instance = dictionary.Where(new SagaQuery<AnswerSetState>(x => x.CorrelationId == answerSetId.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
    instance.Instance.CurrentState = state.Name;

    await AssertInstanceInState(answerSetId.Value, state); // waits until the instance is found in the desired state

    return instance.Instance;
}

protected override async Task AssertInstanceInState(Guid correlationId, State state)
{
    Assert.That((await SagaHarness.Match(x => x.CorrelationId == correlationId && x.CurrentState == state.Name)).Any());
}
```

the properties come from a base class

```
protected TStateMachine Machine;
protected ServiceProvider Provider;
protected ISagaStateMachineTestHarness<TStateMachine, TInstance> SagaHarness;
protected ITestHarness TestHarness;
```

how it's used:

```
[Test]
public async Task When_AnswerSetAutoSaved_And_StateIsDraft_Should_Ignore()
{
    var instance = await CreateInstanceInState(Machine.Draft);
    var answerSetId = instance.CorrelationId;
    var formPackageInstanceId = instance.FormPackageInstanceId;

    await TestHarness.Bus.Publish(new AnswerSetAutosaved
    {
        AnswerSetId = answerSetId,
        FormPackageInstanceId = formPackageInstanceId,
    });

    Assert.That(await SagaHarness.Consumed.Any<AnswerSetAutosaved>());
    Assert.That(await TestHarness.Published.Any<Fault<AnswerSetAutosaved>>(NoSuchMessageTimeout), Is.False);
}
```